# Checkstyle report not displayed in Hudson dashboard

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, pmd

I meet same trouble. The checkstyle_report.xml is OK. 
But the report can not display hudson dashboard.

[image]

[image]

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to start another build. You have to selected to publish those results in the Job Configuration:

Open your Job, select `Configure`, scroll down to `Post-build Actions` and check `Publish Checkstyle analysis results` and the other ones. For each tool you have to specify the paths where the results are located, for example `bin/checkstyle_report.xml`.

Comment: How can I do it? I've checked the "run always" checkbox for the above tools, but I don't know how 'to link' reports results in the PMD/Checkstyle/Findbugs configuration node...

Comment: I'm running Ant. Should I run Maven in order to produce graphics?

Comment: No, if you get valid reports from that tools it is just a configuration issue in jenkins.

Comment: Sometimes for Jenkins/Hudson to show your graph, you need to have more than one build and have to restart it after installing the plugin.

Comment: What should I input into "Checkstyle results" textbox, in order to get .xml report results and 'to plot' it in trends graphics? How can I setup fileset and workspace in it?

Comment: There is no option 'Publish Checkstyle Results' under Post-build Actions.. is this normal?

Comment: @streetlight you have to install the checkstyle plugin and restart jenkins.

Comment: @user714965 I have it installed, and I have an option under 'Build Settings' called 'Publish Checkstyle analysis results' but it doesn't allow me to specify a url it should look for, and I get no feedback. I can't find the Post-build actions portion, and have tried restarting. Is this a new feature?

Comment: I don't even see the icon in the screenshot, but I do have the above feature and have it installed and restarted.

Answer (score -1):

your build runs the maven goal checkstyle:checkstyle